# Why does Chrome require the -webkit- prefix for CSS cursors?

Tags: css, google-chrome, vendor-prefix

The cursor spec is pretty old. Am I missing something in terms of cursors that I should be accounting for in my CSS other than just prefixing the cursor value?

**Edit:** I'm referring specifically to the "grab" property and others like it, which require "-webkit-grab". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: what did you use - `cursor:` should work...

Comment: The cursor property has never existed in any prefixed form in the history of CSS. There *are* certain values new to CSS3 as well as proprietary values that require prefixes in certain browsers, though.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, that's what I meant, sorry. I should have clarified. I'm talking specifically about the "grab" value. I'll update my post

Comment: cursor: grab and cursor: grabbing; work without the prefix in Chrome as of 2021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `grab` value is [new to css-ui-3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/#cursor). This was during a time when anything that was new and experimental came in the form of vendor prefixes, including values. I'm not sure why Chrome hasn't still unprefixed it yet considering Firefox 27, released [two and a half years ago](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/27), now supports this value unprefixed. Microsoft Edge also supports it unprefixed, though Internet Explorer does not.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't, you can use `cursor` just fine in Chrome.

Fully supported in all browsers - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Comment: Flagged as non-constructive comment